# Error in Paraview. IntVectorProperty in xml break the program

Tags: xml, paraview

When I create a ServerManagerConfiguration xml to be used in my built paraview as filter without a vector property (Int, string, double...) works fine and the filter can be used BUT if I add a custom property then I always get this error:

*Debug error!
R6010 - abort() has been called*

I think that maybe the problem is because in properties panel the view+properties sections that you can find in normal paraview, in my built version are missing.

**Edited:**

I have built the whole paraview project (where I guess there are no missing docks) the problem is still there. So If I reduce my xml to just one tag *InputProperty*, it breaks BUT if I change this line:

*< SourceProxy name="name" class="vtkPythonProgrammableFilter" label="name" >*

to

*< SourceProxy name="name" class="vtkCellDerivatives" label="name" >*

this change is done just to test if the problem was there. Well it was!! So the problem is when I use *vtkPythonProgrammableFilter* … but I need to use it to be able to create my own python filter... any idea?

Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abort() should have a debug message before it aborts. Can you print that debug message. Alternatively, to a "debug" build of ParaVIew and then attach a debugger and then look at the call stack. That should indicate why it's aborting.

I suspect you didn't build ParaView with Python support enabled. Are you able to access the *Python shell* from the **Tools** menu?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought but I have tried to build everything again with Python support enabled but I always get this error when I try to run a normal example (in build folder) "?IsTypeOf@vtkPyhtonAnnotationFilter@@SAHPEBD@Z is not found in the dll vtkPVClientServerCoreCore-pv4.dll". any idea?

Comment: What version of ParaView are you trying to build?

Comment: I have built the 4.1 again with shared libraries (to be able to manage plugings) and Python enabled. I though that maybe there was a mistake in my last build so I built it again and now its working.